# left join doesn't work - its ignoring the records of the left table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables

Table CUSTOMER

```
ID NUMBER NAME
--------------------------------------
1  12345  Apple
2  23456  Orange
3  25896  Banana
```

Table ACCOUNT

```
 ID    CUST_NUMBR  TYPE    BILLING_FK
 -------------------------------------
 1     12345        B      9876
 2     23456        R      8765
 3     25896        R      7654
```

Table BILLING

```
 ID    Start_Date  End_Date 
 -------------------------------------
 1     BLAH       BLAH       
 2     BLAH       BLAH             
 3     BLAH       BLAH
```

Relations

```
  CUSTOMER.NUMBER = ACCOUNT.CUST_NUMBR
  ACCOUNT.BILLING_FK  = BILLING.ID
```

Sometimes Account won't be found for a Customer, in that case the start date has to be null.

If I try with left join I don't see the customer if it doesn't have a account.

```
 select name,number,start_date
 from customer left join account on customer.number = account.cust_number,
 billing
 where account.billing_fk = billing.id
```

How to get the start date as null if there is no account for that customer.

Answer (score 5):

You condition `account.billing_fk = billing.id` turns your `LEFT JOIN` into `INNER JOIN`.  It's pretty much eliminating all `NULL` entries.

```
select name,number,start_date
from customer 
left join account on customer.number = account.cust_number
left join billing on account.billing_fk = billing.id
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because of the following statement in you where clause:

```
account.billing_fk = billing.id
```

Try to move it to the `left join section`